# RegEx Relace in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, regex

i have a large mysql database.

i want to remove all `<div id="varies every time"> .... </div>` in this database.

means, `<div {id=xx|class=xxx|style=xxx} >` AND `</div>` should be removed content between them should not be edited.

I can simply remove all `</div>`s from table.

but the problem is `<div          >` cause every time this part will change.

Hope you understand the point.

Is it possible to do like that with MySQL Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not do it with MySQL.

You can easily do this with simple PHP loop.

If you prefer MySQL however, you can take a look at this https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp